# pandas summing up columns by group

Tags: python, pandas

I have a dataframe like such:

```
   Bool  Count State
0     0      1    CA
1     1      1    CA
2     1      1    VT
3     0      1    CA
```

I wanted to group them all such that I get the number of all values of CA that are 0,1, etc, and I applied the following code:

```
df.groupby(["State","Bool"]).sum()
```

And it gives me:

```
            Count
State Bool       
CA    0         2
      1         1
VT    1         1
```

How do I output this in a JSON format?

Comment: can't you simply use `df.groupby(["State","Bool"]).sum().to_json()`?

Comment: It really depends on the required format of your JSON.

Comment: @JulienSpronck That gives a JSON in the format {"Count":{"["CA",0]":2,"["CA",1]":2,"["VT",0]":2,"["VT",1]":1}}, whereas I want it in the format {"State":"CA","Bool":0,"Count":2}